# Не получается прописать статичные файлы для сайта в Express

Tags: node.js, express

Запустил через node.js простейший сервер на локалхосте, чтобы собрать примитивный лендинг CSS + HTML. Поставил пакет Express, собственно, для того чтобы его запустить. Запускаю командой `$ node server.js`

server.js

```html
// берём Express
var express = require('express');
   //var path = require('path');

// создаём Express-приложение
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));

// создаём маршрут для главной страницы
// http://localhost:8080/
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// запускаем сервер на порту 8080
app.listen(8080);
// отправляем сообщение
console.log('started');
```

В браузере при запуске сервера куча ошибок вида:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/js/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Хотя статичные маршруты у меня прописаны. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что когда вы пишите вот так:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

Вы говорите Express что **все** файлы надо искать в директории `__dirname + '/js'`. И в итоге ваш `script.js` ищется по пути `__dirname + '/js/js/script.js'`

Чтобы отобразить несколько конкретных папок в качестве папок со статикой - надо использовать форму с префиксом:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, есть существенная  разница, между мои и твоим вариантом? Я ответил не потому, что точно знаю ответ, а потому, что у меня это железно работает...  Я  с трудом этот `NodeJS` понимаю, все еще его грызу потихоньку....  Поделись опытом...

Comment: @Air да, есть. Вы предлагаете автору изменить структуру проекта, а я написал как сделать чтобы существующая структура работала

Comment: Это я понял...  Я же не утверждаю, что мой ответ лучше и хуже... Меня интересует вот из этих двух вариантов, что лучше....??

Comment: @Air идеологически ваш, наверное, лучше, поскольку явно отделяет статику от динамики. Но этот может чуть-чуть шустрее работать (минус системный вызов на запрос).

Comment: Благодарю, я понял....

Answer (score 1):

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.listen(8080);
var server = http.createServer(app);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); 
// вот эти папки js, css, images, сунь в папку "public"
// ну или назови ее как хочешь  по другому
```